# Samsung internet warping a tag within p tag

Tags: android, html, wordpress, mobile, samsung-mobile

I am managing a website and testing for mobile.  On Samsung Internet which comes standard with Galaxy phones (I am seeing this on Galaxy S6 and Galaxy Note 5) there is a link on my page that displays as "irndog> indahy.mds"
[image: Weird text in footer on samsung browser]

The site is built on wordpress, however this is hardcoded into the template as HTML.  Here is the code:

```
<p id="rightFooter">Feel free to contact me at <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a></p>
```

If I remove the a tag from the p tag and keep it seperate, the problem disappears. I also tried making the link a normal link instead of a mailto: as well as changing the text of the link. Neither solved the problem.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Hm, no clues with what was given in the question. But these characters can't be random, I bet they're coming from somewhere else in the file. Maybe searching for "irn" or "irndog" in the file gives you something?

Comment: The letters change when you change the words in the link.  Also I performed a search in my files for that combination of letters with no results.

Comment: Could you please share a link or a test case that reproduces it?

Comment: In true annoying tiny problem fashion, it seems to have resolved itself on its own.  Thanks for your attention!